# Set up android wear UI library on intelij idea

Tags: android, intellij-idea, wear-os

I'm trying to set up the Android Wear development environment in Intellij Idea.

I have extracted the jar from the: `sdk\sdk\extras\google\m2repository\com\google\android\support\wearable\1.0.0\` and I've renamed the `classes.jar` to something more human readable.
I have created a library project from the extracted files and I've added my `classes.jar` as exported library, and I've liked this library module to my application.

Everything compiled, everything worked but when I've deployed I've got this error:

```
Process: com.garmin.mech.wear, PID: 5343
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.support.wearable.R$styleable
        at android.support.wearable.view.BoxInsetLayout$LayoutParams.<init>(BoxInsetLayout.java:340)
        at android.support.wearable.view.BoxInsetLayout.generateLayoutParams(BoxInsetLayout.java:321)
        at android.support.wearable.view.BoxInsetLayout.generateLayoutParams(BoxInsetLayout.java:25)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:757)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:309)
        at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1930)
        at com.garmin.mech.wear.MyActivity.onCreate(MyActivity.java:16)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5242)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2161)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2258)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:138)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1209)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5026)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:602)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

The XML file that causes this issue looks like this:

```
<android.support.wearable.view.BoxInsetLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:background="@drawable/card_frame"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">

<FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_box="bottom">

</FrameLayout>
```

Can somebody point me to something I can work with ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you got the error is because you unpacked an AAR and didn't keep the resources. AAR = JAR + resources essentially. You're missing something from R.styleable and if you look in the res/values folder you'll see there are a bunch of styles defined for the wearables support library.

You're probably missing this:

```
<declare-styleable name="BoxInsetLayout">
    <attr name="layout_box">
        <flag name="left" value="0x01" />
        <flag name="top" value="0x02" />
        <flag name="right" value="0x04" />
        <flag name="bottom" value="0x08" />
        <flag name="all" value="0x0F" />
    </attr>
</declare-styleable>
```

You might find you need the drawables too.

If you extract the AAR as follows it should work:

```
mkdir wearable-1.0.0
unzip wearable-1.0.0.aar -d wearable-1.0.0
mkdir wearable-1.0.0/libs
mv wearable-1.0.0/classes.jar wearable-1.0.0/libs
```

Comment: Actually the declared-styleable is there, but the issue still persists.

Comment: Philio, is the wearable library module dependent on other libraries too? I suspect that there is a dependency I miss.  I will try to wipe out everything and try again with what you've suggested, and I will come back with an answer :) Thanks

Comment: I actually pulled up the instructions for Eclipse, it doesn't suggest that the play services wearable library is required (although Android Studio adds it by default in the Gradle build file), what it does seem to suggest is that the contents of the AAR are important - you need to make sure you have everything. An AAR is basically a zipped library project so that makes sense.